# How to solve wrong TypeScript Error occuranse in WebStorm?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webstorm

I have a completely new Vue.js installation by `npm init vue@latest`.
Using WebStorm.

Now I get TypeScript Errors 'Cannot find module' on places like in main.ts  `import App from './App.vue'` will throw Error: `TS2307: Cannot find module './App.vue' or its corresponding type declarations.`.

How can that be and how to fix?

I tried various things.
I tried e.g. adding a vue.d.ts with following content:

```
declare module '*.vue' {
  import type {DefineComponent} from 'vue'
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  const component: DefineComponent<object, object, any>
  export default component
}
```

But then I get Errors also on main.ts on line `import { createApp } from 'vue'` , which throws the Error: `S2306: File '/vue.d.ts' is not a module.`.

Im very grateful for help! :pray:

Answer (score 1):

As of bad Vue.js and TypeScript 5.0 Support, the WebStorm IDE shows errors incorrectly.

I solved the Issues by trying the Webstorm 2023.2 RC Version today.

Comment: Solves it not for me. I have the same issue with either '@/Main.vue' import or 'vue' import, if I create a vue.d.ts.